# LINUX: How can I recursively zip files in sub-folders?

Tags: linux, zip, archive, directory-structure, 7zip

I have the following directory structure:

```
/Data
 - file 1
 - file 2

  /Folder1

   - file 3
   - file 4

  /Folder2
   - file 5
   - file 6

    /Folder3
      - file 7
      - file 8
```

In **Linux** I want to zip **files** (excluding folders) in every directory and create a 7z (or zip) archive in each folder resulting the following:

```
/Data
     Data.7z (Note: this should contain only file1 & 2, not any sub directories)

      /Folder1

       Folder1.7z (this should contain only file3 & 4, not any sub directories)

      /Folder2
       Folder2.7z (this should contain only file5 & 6, no Folder3)

        /Folder3
          Folder3.7z (should contain only file7 & 8)
```

Following script works on the first directory but not on the sub-directories : `for i in */ ; do base=$(basename “$i”) ; cd $base ; 7za a -t7z -r $base * ; .. ; cd .. ; done;`

How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Hope this helps somebody : find Data -type d -execdir sh -c 'cd "$1" && 7z a "$1".7z -x!*/ && cd -' sh {} \;

Comment: More here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005614/how-can-i-recursively-zip-files-in-their-own-folder/1005650#1005650